# Add PJL command into PDF file with PHP code

Tags: php, pdf, zend-framework, pjl

How can I insert a PJL command  into PDF without having to convert PDF to PostScript

```
*STARTPJL
@PJL SET STAPLE=LEFTTOP
*ENDPJL
```

after I send it to printer via FTP or LPR.

I'm using Zend_Pdf to create PDF documents.

**I tried unsuccessfully this code

```
$a .= "<ESC>%-12345X@PJL<CR><LF>";
$a .= "@PJL SET OUTBIN=OUTBIN101<CR><LF>";
$a .= "@PJL SET STAPLE=LEFTTOP<CR><LF>";
$a .= "@PJL ENTER LANGUAGE = PDF<CR><LF>";
$a .= file_get_contents("/www/zendsvr/htdocs/GDA/public/pdf/test.pdf");
$a .= "<ESC>%-12345X";

$myfile = fopen("/www/zendsvr/htdocs/GDA/public/pdf/t.pdf", "w");
fwrite($myfile, $a);
fclose($myfile);
```

the document is printed correctly but does not change the drawe and not clamp, any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<sub>I'm not going to explain how to achieve the following points with PHP. These points merely explain the most important fundamentals to be familiar with when dealing with PJL and with PJL regarding PDF-based print jobs. You have to 'translate' this generic info to PHP yourself....</sub>

---

You cannot ***insert*** PJL commands *into* PDF. But you can ***prepend*** PJL commands to a PDF print job.

Also, it is not meaningful to do this *after* you send it to a printer via FTP or via LPR. It is only meaningful if you do it *before* sending the file.

Next, your example PJL code is not valid for most purposes. The standard way to prepend PJL lines to a PDF print job file is this:

```
<ESC>%-12345X@PJL<CR><LF>
@PJL SET STAPLE=LEFTTOP<CR><LF>
@PJL    [... more PJL commands if required ...]
@PJL ENTER LANGUAGE = PDF<CR><LF>
[... all bytes of the PDF file, starting with '%PDF-1.' ...]
[... all bytes of the PDF file ............................]
[... all bytes of the PDF file ............................]
[... all bytes of the PDF file, ending with '%%EOF' .......]
<ESC>%-12345X
```

***Explanations:***

- Here `<ESC>` denotes the *escape* character (`27` in decimal, `1B` in hex).
- `<CR>` denotes the *carriage return* character (`13` in dec, `0D` in hex). It is *optional* within PJL.
- `<LF>` denotes the *line feed* charaxter (`10` in dec, `0A` in hex). It is *required* within PJL.
- `<ESC>%-12345X` denotes the *'Universal Exit Language'*  command (UEL). It is *required* in PJL. It defines beginning and end of any PJL-based data stream.

**Lastly, please note:**

1. Not all printers and not all LPR print services are able to deal with PDF-based print jobs.
2. Also, not all printers and not all LPR print services are able to honor PJL commands which are prepended to print job files.

Comment: thanks for your answer, when you say "prepend" do you think that i can put it in only one file to send to the printer or can i send the command as a directive to the protocol?

Comment: If the printer supports it at all, it can + should be in one file!

Comment: @jack.cap.rooney: My answer is correct (and almost complete). It *still* should have taught you something. Because the example code you used in your question was *wrong*. Also, your printer may ***(1)*** Not support PJL, ***(2)*** not support DirectPDF printing.